# initialize a listview outside of a page

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am building a single page application using jQuery Mobile.

In the header I have a "menu" button that opens a popup with a listview.

I would like to define this popup dialog and reuse it for all pages.

Reusing a popup outside a page works fine, but listview inside the popup does not get enhanced (because listview internally uses parent page to resolve links included in the list).

Question: is it possible to use a listview widget outside of a page? (I do understand that I might have to specify a base url for this to work, but I don't think that will be a problem).

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible. When you create a dynamic popup, which doesnt reside in a single page, IT WILL WORK, because popups were never meant to be used/page. But, listview on the other hand, **requires** the list to lie in a parent page. The `refresh` method of listview expects it to be in parent. Look at this function which is called when a listview refresh happens :

```
_createSubPages: function () {
    var parentList = this.element,
        parentPage = parentList.closest(".ui-page"), //<-- This line
        parentUrl = parentPage.jqmData("url"), 
        parentId = parentUrl || parentPage[0][$.expando],
        parentListId = parentList.attr("id"),
        o = this.options,
        dns = "data-" + $.mobile.ns,
        self = this,
        persistentFooterID = parentPage.find(":jqmData(role='footer')").jqmData("id"),
        hasSubPages;

      // blah blee blah

    }).listview();
```

See the second line in the function. It expects a page to be there. Tough luck bro :)

PS : This is the closest i could get : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/8qq62/1/

**EDIT**

Here's a hacky way. You could dynamically create a *hidden* `<span/>` in your `data-role=page` `div` and add the `<ul/>` in it. Then you could refresh it, after which you could move it to the dynamic popup. Then you'll have to remove that hidden span element. Here's the code :

```
$.extend({
    "makePopup": function (array) { //you could add more if you want here, such as callbacks to the click function of the button,etc.
        var $popup;
        //creat popup element
        $popup = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "popup",
                "data-theme": "a",
                "data-overlay-theme": "a",
                "data-transition": "pop"
        }).popup();

        //create list
        $list = $("<ul/>", {
            "data-role": "listview",
                "id": "templist"
        }).html(function () {
            var li = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                li.push($("<li/>").html(array[i]));
            }
            return li;
        })

        //create close element
        var $close = $("<a/>", {
            "data-role": "button",
                "html": "Close",
                "href": "#",
                "data-theme": "a"
        }).on("click", function () {
            //click event of close element
            $(this).closest("[data-role=popup]").popup("close");
        }).buttonMarkup();

        //add a span to page, refresh list, etc
        $.mobile.activePage.append("<span id='temp'></span>").find("#temp").hide().append($list).promise().done(function () {
            $(this).find("#templist").listview().listview("refresh");
        });

        //create content div - makes a nice jQM page structure.
        var $content = $("<div/>", {
            "data-role": "content",
            //move li to popup
        }).append($("#temp").find("#templist"), $close);
        //remove span
        $("#temp").remove();
        //append $close to $content, then append $content to $popup
        $content.appendTo($popup) 
        return $popup;
    }

});
```

And you could pass an array to this :

```
 $.makePopup(["Sweet Child 'O Mine", "Summer of '69", "Smoke in the Water", "Enter Sandman", "I thought I've seen everything"]).popup("open");
```

Here's an updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/8qq62/7/

But obviously this is hacky.